# instance from Lookup object

Tags: java, instance, java-7, lookup, bootstrapping

If you have an arbitrary Lookup object (generated from invokedynamic bootstrap), is it possible to get an instance from the class performing the lookup?

There is a Method "lookupClass" available for Lookup objects, but that only returns a Class object.

Lets say I have a Class Car for example, which generates a Lookup object.
How can i get an instance of that class?

Thanks.

Comment: need some examples/more information of what you have already.

Comment: I have the method: 
public static java.lang.invoke.CallSite wrapandinject(Lookup caller, String name, MethodType type)

that is used as bootstrapmethod for invokedynamic bytecode. So the Lookup object is caller and it points to a class in the bytecode that is not directly accessible from eclipse

Comment: Do you need the whole source code? - My intension was to use the instance as receiver in an invokexact call on a maethodhandle..

hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution :)

If you have a lookup object caller, then you can get the instance of the class performing the lookup with the following line:

Class.forName(caller.lookupClass().getCanonicalName()).newInstance();